# Syntax error Invalid Regular expression angular typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, microsoft-graph-api, syntax-error, msal.js

i am getting this error and i am stuck cant find where is the syntax problem

> core.mjs:6495 ERROR SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression:
> /https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/communications/callRecords/getPstnCalls(fromDateTime=2020-01-30,toDateTime=2020-01-30/:
> Unterminated group
> at new RegExp ()
> at Function.StringUtils.matchPattern (StringUtils.js:122)
> at azure-msal-angular.js:425
> at Array.forEach ()
> at MsalInterceptor.matchResourcesToEndpoint (azure-msal-angular.js:422)
> at MsalInterceptor.getScopesForEndpoint (azure-msal-angular.js:404)
> at MsalInterceptor.intercept (azure-msal-angular.js:336)
> at HttpInterceptorHandler.handle (http.mjs:1415)
> at HttpXsrfInterceptor.intercept (http.mjs:2018)
> at HttpInterceptorHandler.handle (http.mjs:1415)

```
export function MSALInterceptorConfigFactory(): MsalInterceptorConfiguration {
  
 var fromDatetimeVariable ='2020-01-30';
 var toDatetimeVariable='2020-01-30';

  let queryUrl = `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/communications/callRecords/getPstnCalls(fromDateTime=${fromDatetimeVariable},toDateTime=${toDatetimeVariable}`

  const protectedResourceMap = new Map<string, Array<string>>();
  protectedResourceMap.set(queryUrl, ['CallRecords.Read.All', 'CallRecord-PstnCalls.Read.All']);
  
 // protectedResourceMap.set('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me', ['CallRecord-PstnCalls.Read.All', 'mail.read']);
 // protectedResourceMap.set('http://localhost:8080/hello', ['api://d16e1a06-3be2-4ae1-8bd4-718c19cecac3/hello']);

  return {
    interactionType: InteractionType.Popup,
    protectedResourceMap
  };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have missed to close the parentheses in the queryUrl value. To correct this, your queryUrl value must be like:

```
let queryUrl = `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/communications/callRecords/getPstnCalls(fromDateTime=${fromDatetimeVariable},toDateTime=${toDatetimeVariable})`
```